# JQuery onclick if

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-5

For my burger menu, i can't close de collapse menu.

Please find my code to open the collapse menu.
Could you please tell me how can i add the code to close when i click on the burger menu

I guess, it's work with an 'if' function

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function (event) {
    $('#mynavbar-nav').removeClass('collapse');
    $('#mynavbar-nav').addClass('collapsed');
});
```

and the navbar

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar-nav">
          <?php mymenu_nav(); ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: I need to check the docs, but shouldn't your `data-bs-target` value match the id of the thing you are trying to target?

Comment: https://bootstrapshuffle.com/classes/navbar/navbar-toggler  Yeah, you don't have matching values for the target and the id on the element

Comment: Oh !!! thank you. i didn't see that. @Taplar